# Does it make sense if I edit a question to be more precise?

Tags: discussion

I am thinking about the question [How did communist authorities decide who is "German" and who is "Polish" when expelling Germans from recovered territories?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23073/how-did-communist-authorities-decide-who-is-german-and-who-is-polish-when-ex)

The first answer can be summarized as "This depends on the region" and the second on "I've heard from xxxx that it was very obvious".

Although I upvoted both answers and accepted one of them, and that my question was popular in voting, I realize that I did not get the answer I'd expect, but also that my question might not have been clear enough and not show enough previous research.

I'd want to narrow my question down to a particular region of Poland, and for a particular class of people that could be potentially expelled. The reason for that is that I have ancestors that had lived in those areas, and while they left Germany before the war, I wish to know if, hypothetically they stayed there and somehow survived the Nazi regime and the war, if they would have been expelled or not. I have absolutely no clue how they would have been considered "german" or "polish", especially considering I'm not even sure which language they spoke, officially they were german, but the ethnicity is not part of the official documents in Germany (as opposed to USSR for example).

The answers are not helpful to give me a hint on whether *they would have been expulsed*. Of course, this leaves the "general" question and enters into the "personal" domain, which is off-topic, thus while I've left my question general. This could almost go to Genealogy SE, but not quite.

However if I edit my question to ask about a particular category of people living in a particular region of Poland, that will instantly make both answers terribly off topic, and that would not be the answerer's fault.

However, if I do re-ask a similar question but with more insight, it will be marked as a duplicate of the first question.

EDIT: Thus I do not know exactly what should I do in order to get the answer I'd like to. However I'm also afraid such an answer does not exist, looking how random and lawless those expulsions were.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is no simple answer to this. I would advise you to ask a new question, reference the existing question, and make it explicit that you're looking for more precise answers.

Comment: Well the more I think about it, the more I belive it do not make sense to ask a question that is 90% the same. I belive that editing my question and commenting the answers as "I invite you to edit your answer to adress my last edit" would be a better idea.

Comment: @Bregalad As a rule, editing a question to make existing answers obsolete is frowned upon. Asking a separate question as Mark suggested is a better idea. There can be many questions asked on the same topic, as long as the focus of the question is different. It helps to be specific.